# what field type should we give for longitude and latitude columns in flask models to create table in postgresql?

Tags: sql, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I wanted to create a database table in Flask which consists of longitude and latitude fields in table?So what should be the field types for those?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your database type, you'll probably want a numeric type that supports decimals. PostgreSQL supports `double precision`, which you can use like so:

```py
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import DOUBLE_PRECISION
```

or

```py
db = SQLAlchemy()
db.DOUBLE_PRECISION
```

Keep in mind that you're prone to floating point errors with decimals, so when you want to know whether latitude/longitude values have changed, it may be smart to round them to a specific number of decimals and/or use `numpy.isclose` to compare the old and new values